# MIPS: Creating a string from bytes read

Tags: string, assembly, mips, c-strings, mars-simulator

I'm reading a string from a buffer, and at some point I need to stop and get the string of what I've read so far and get the size of this string, so let's say I've the string: "`StackOverflow`" and going to use "`v`" as my stop point, so I should have something like "`StackO`" as my result string.

The thing is, to count the size of it, I'm reading byte by byte, so when I get to the stop point, the register `$t0` which is counting the size of it should have the value 6 in it. So, how can I create a string that has "`Stack0`" in it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using null-terminated strings, you can either a) copy the string to another buffer and add a 0 (null character) after the 6th character, or b) put the 0 in the original buffer after the 6th character, overwriting the ‘v’, if you don’t mind destroying the original string.

Comment: How would I put the 0 after the 6th character?

Comment: @PauloCalado: `sb $0, ($t1)`, where `$t1` is the pointer to the `'v'` you already have (because you had to load it in the first place).

Comment: Thank you very much sir!